# how to activate overprint and transparency flattener options in Adobe Illustrator cs6

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I used to save PDF with extracted Text from Illustrator using the `overprint and transparency flattener options` without any problem till yesterday.

yesterday I cleaned up my PC using AVG PC TuneUp 2014 since that action I couldn't export anymore from Illustrator as extracted PDF text file.
the overprint and transparency flattener options is disabled as shown hereunder

[image]

I tried to restore all what AVG TuneUp did but nothing happened, and I get a dimmed dialogue box. And I have noticed that all software that have this option is disabled too, like indesign. 
I also tried to rest all software settings to its first installed settings as usual ways but i get nothing.

my Question is how to restore or re-activate the "overprint and transparency flattener options" ?
I am using Acrobat 11 over Windows 7 ultimate and Creative Suite CS6

Note: This is not a graphics design issue, it is a technical issue.

Comment: A radical way to try getting things back would be dumping and reinstalling Illustrator (and maybe also Acrobat). You may also think about using Acrobat to do the final preparation for printing, maybe by using the Preflight tool and an according fixup. And a hint about the transparency flattener… do that in Acrobat too, and select ZIP compression; the JPEG compression Adobe uses in their settings is horrendous (probably 5), and creates bad artefacts.

Comment: I tried to re-install Acrobat but i didn't help. the last thing I have to try is to reinstall Illustrator and Indesign.

Comment: I think it is more an Illustrator and InDesign issue than Acrobat, because it is where the PDF is created; in this context Acrobat is "just the messenger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the great feature in the "trancparency flattener options" in Adobe Illustrator is to convert all texts to outline. That feature let me work in a single file avoiding me to work in two versions of the file one with text and the other with outline texts. So When I want to export my PDF file to the printshop, I will avoid all the copyrights issues related to the font I am using and avoiding sending the font with the file to the print shop.
but this feature doesn't work without the existing of any overprint and transparency in the file. I mean I must have anything in the file that is overprinted.

The case is ... I don't have any overprint objects in my file, while I still want to export my PDF with all my texts converted to outlines while saving to PDF to prepare my file for the print shop.

I discovered recently that "overprint and transparency flattener options" " will be active if I have any overprint objects(s) in my document. which I belief it is not logic.

**The trick in InDesign is: create a transparent object somewhere (where it doesn't ruin anything) and then you can run the flattener in the Save dialog. it work in Illustrator as well.**